# ASP.NET API does not start in docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core

I have a very simple asp net rest API solution.  - NET 3.1
My docker file is a standard one added from visual studio.
My app runs locally in docker and everything is fine.
I have pushed my image to docker hub and after I pulled it to my remote server (which already runs some dockerized apps with no problems) it just doesn't start, it just exited  immediately

Here is prtn scrn of my docker ps command
[image]

My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MetaRegistar.API/MetaRegistar.API.csproj", "MetaRegistar.API/"]
COPY ["MetaRegistar.BL/MetaRegistar.BL.csproj", "MetaRegistar.BL/"]
COPY ["MetaRegistar.Data/MetaRegistar.Data.csproj", "MetaRegistar.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MetaRegistar.API/MetaRegistar.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MetaRegistar.API"
RUN dotnet build "MetaRegistar.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MetaRegistar.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MetaRegistar.API.dll"]
```

I tried to run it with this command:
docker run -d --name mrapi -p 82:80 gbralo/mrapi:3.0

And just to be sure, my app worked very fine 2 days ago, when I had few changes and tried to deploy a new version this happens.
And I am desperate right now.

UPDATE:
This is what happens when I try to build an image from visual studio (right click -> build image)
[image]

When i run build in terminal
[image]

```
        C:\Users\gbral\Documents\GitHub\meta-registar-api\MetaRegistar\MetaRegistar.API>docker build -t mrapi .
    [+] Building 1.5s (5/5) FINISHED
     => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
     => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/base:latest                                         
1.4s
     => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1                                 
0.3s
     => [auth] library/base:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                        0.0s
    ------
     > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/base:latest:
    ------
    failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

What do the logs say?

first run `docker ps -a` to get a list containers including ones with a status of Exited.
Then run `docker logs <container-id>` where you replace container-id with the id of your container e.g. `docker logs 5484ec`

Other thing you could do to test, remove the `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MetaRegistar.API.dll"]` line from your Dockerfile and then after building the image run `docker run -it --name mrapi -p 82:80 gbralo/mrapi:3.0 /bin/bash` and then from within the running container, run the command `dotnet MetaRegistar.API.dll --verbosity diagnostic` from within the container and see what it does/says...

Comment: Thanks for answering
My logs are empty nothing there.
Is there a problem maybe because I build a docker image with visual studio, I start my app in docker, and then I see images
Docker build from the terminal gives me an error like exited with status code 1,
and ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/base:latest

Comment: is the docker build even working? Any errors? One thing that looks a bit strange in your multi-stage Dockerfile is that you've got 4 images (i.e build-env, build, publish, & final)... I usually just have 2; build & runtime - keep it simple.

Comment: I have just updated my question with an error when I click build image
When I run it locally in visual studio, using docker, it runs. but build fails
Any thoughts on this error

Comment: I don't know about docker error in Visual Studio... can you try running `docker build -t mrapi .` in the dir where the Dockerfile is (assume there's no --build-args or anything)...

Comment: Yes, i did that, there is an error, i posted prtscrn in question above.
=>ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/base:latest

Comment: Please post text rather than prtscrn. The part of the log that matters there is: _Pull access denied. Repository doesn't exist or may require authorisation_

Comment: If you're able to, perhaps re-run docker build in completely clean environment - you can run the following commands to clear out all containers and images; `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` and `docker rmi $(docker ps -a -q)`. Note; these commands will stop and remove all running containers, as well as images requiring you to download images again during subsequent builds, so just be careful...

Comment: It is not problem at all to clean all that and re run docker build. Problem is Here that i dont know what is error here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MetaRegistar.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
```

Change the last line to `FROM publish AS final`